# Can I reset mouse speed in OSX?

Tags: macos

Over the years I've tried various solutions like Steermouse to fix my tracking settings with various mice.  I'm not entirely sure which settings these programs have altered, and it doesn't seem like those settings are reverted when I uninstall the control panels for Steermouse, etc.  Is there a clean way to reset the mouse settings without a complete reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases, simply going to your Mouse system preference and modifying the settings in there (such as tracking speed) will automatically revert all changes made by third party tools since this is when OS X overwrites any changes that were made by those tools.